create a python AI model that can read PCB layout image
can someone please help me create this project
i need to understand how to start it what do i need and the steps.
i never created AI model before.
** create AI model that can read PCB layout image (png.) and generate Gerber file for it.
using python (pytorch)

This is a relatively advanced project. Can you clarify what you have (files, knowledge, existing project)?

i have a dataset of PCB images with their related Gerber files

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Creating an AI model that can read a PCB layout image (e.g., a PNG file) and generate a corresponding Gerber file is a complex task that involves several steps. You may need to break it down and do your own research!
